# \reflectbox in \newenvironment

Tags: formatting, environments, text-manipulation

I have the following problem with the `\reflectbox{}` command used in a `\newenvironment{}`: It doesn't do anything. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{solution}[1]{\reflectbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

    Hello \reflectbox{World}.

    \begin{solution}
        This should not be readable, but it is.
    \end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: argument of your environment means that you are going to start the environment like `\begin{solution}{Some text to be reflected} Some other text not reflected\end{solution}` ... May be you want to use a command and not an environment.

Comment: ah, ok, thanks for the easy solution! Is there a rule when I need to add additional {...} in an evironment and when not? I want to use an enviroment to be able to do more extensive stuff later on. Reflectbox was just one part of the formatting stuff.

Comment: The way you define the environment: i.e. `\newenvironment{myenvironment}[4][<Default Value>]{<do something before its content>}{<do something after its content>}` ... means that it needs 3 mandatory and one optional arguments that the optional will be by default equal to `<Default Value>`... Feel free to open a new thread and ask for the way to do exactly what you want to get ... A MWE will help but additional info about what is the purpose of the environment will be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first gather the contents in a box, using `minipage` inside so as to cope with paragraphs.

Then you can reflect the box.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\solutionbox}
\newenvironment{solution}
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\solutionbox}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \noindent\reflectbox{\usebox{\solutionbox}}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
 }

\begin{document}

Hello \reflectbox{World}.

\begin{solution}
This should not be readable, and it isn't.
This should not be readable, and it isn't.
This should not be readable, and it isn't.
This should not be readable, and it isn't.
This should not be readable, and it isn't.
This should not be readable, and it isn't.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's also a good solution. And this new enviroment doesn't "eat up" the linebreaks which would normally happen. Could you elaborate a bit on whyt/how this works? You are putting a minipage into a lrbox and the reflectbox comes afterwards?

Comment: @burningman I set the text in a minipage with the standard text width, so it can be broken across lines. The minipage is packed in a save box, which is delivered after reflecting it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `environ` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{solution}{\reflectbox{\BODY}}

\begin{document}

    Hello \reflectbox{World}.

    \begin{solution}
        This should not be readable, but it is.
    \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Another solution with `adjustbox` and no need of `environ`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{solution}{\adjustbox{reflect}\bgroup}{\egroup}

\begin{document}

Hello \reflectbox{World}.

\begin{solution}
    This should not be readable, but it is.
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And an additional way without other packages but a `\savebox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mybox

\newenvironment{solution}{\savebox\mybox\bgroup\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup\egroup\reflectbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}

\begin{document}

    Hello \reflectbox{World}.

    \begin{solution}
        This should not be readable, but it is.

        Some other text
    \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]